# A strong neodymium magnet has no effect whatsoever on my phone compass. How is that possible?

Tags: magnetic-fields, geomagnetism

If I hold a strong neodymium magnet near my iPhone while the compass app is running, there is no effect whatsoever on the compass bearing. It doesn't matter where I hold the magnet in relation to the phone, nor which way the magnet itself is oriented.

It also doesn't matter if I hold the magnet near the phone before I start the compass app (I thought perhaps that the compass app might take an initial bearing and then use the phone's gyroscopes to calculate offsets from this).

How is this possible?

Clarification: the compass on the phone is working perfectly as a compass i.e. it indicates magnetic north correctly. So the compass is somehow indicating earth's magnetic field while not being susceptible to nearby strong magnet.

Comment: Is your magnet a simple dipole? or is it some kind of _[array magnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halbach_array)_ that is intended for sticking papers to a metal surface? If it's the latter, then there might not be much disturbance in the ambient field more than a centimeter or so from the surface of the magnet.

Comment: P.S.; If the magnet has one face that sticks tight to a flat metal surface, but the opposite face is only weakly attracted or not attracted at all, then it probably is some kind of array magnet.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone has a Hall effect/magnetometer, not a magnet (https://theoryandpractice.citizenscienceassociation.org/articles/10.5334/cstp.158/) - you can look up the model Alps Electric HSCDTD007

Comment: Right but shouldn't this be susceptible to the magnetic field from a nearby magnet?

Comment: It is a bit difficult to find documentation but I am convinced that these sensors by Alps Electric use AMR (anisotropic magnetoresistance) and not the Hall effect.

Comment: This would be better as a comment. It isn't an answer.

Comment: @Pieter : A similar part is a Hall sensor (https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ALPS/HSCDTD008A?utm_term=HSCDTD&qs=hqbSiJllDNPYrrLcxpWFpw%3D%3D&utm_campaign=HSCDTD008A&utm_medium=aggregator&utm_source=findchips&utm_content=ALPS)

Comment: That is something Mouser wrote, I do not think it is correct. Alps holds some patents in AMR, and I believe theirs work in the same way as the competition: https://aerospace.honeywell.com/en/~/media/aerospace/files/technical-articles/sensors_product_catalog.pdf

Comment: @Pieter : You don't think it is correct. Mouser thinks it is correct. With all due respect, your arguments are not convincing. For example, the previous magnetometer AK8973 used in iphones (https://www.memsjournal.com/2011/02/motion-sensing-in-the-iphone-4-electronic-compass.html) was a Hall effect sensor (https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/219477/AKM/AK8973.html) .

Comment: AMR sensors use much less current than Hall sensors for the same sensitivity, which is important in mobile phones. AMR devices have improved and now totally dominate the market for electronic compasses. Alps is well aware (but this is for a different application): https://www.alps.com/e/faq/sensor_magnetic/magnetic_switching.html

Comment: @Pieter : So far we cannot find reliable info on the Alps sensor principle, but at least some iphone compasses are definitely Hall effect (AK8973).

Answer (score 1):

A phone electronic compass usually uses AMR (anisotropic magnetorestivity), four of those sensors in a Wheatstone bridge for each axis. Typically, they saturate at about 10 gauss (Earth's magnetic field is 0.5 gauss).

After exposed to a strong magnetic field, degaussing is necessary. This is usually triggered by moving the phone in a figure-8-pattern.

So try that first. Then approach carefully from a distance with a magnet.

Comment: Just to be clear, the compass on the phone is working perfectly as a compass i.e. it indicates magnetic north correctly. So the compass is somehow indicating earth's magnetic fiield while not being susceptible to nearby strong magnet.

Comment: @RonanCremin Have you tested with a classic needle compass next to your phone?

Comment: I once stacked a whole bunch of small neodymium magnets end-to-end to make a "bar" magnet about 10cm long, and I tried it on my phone. Turning the magnet caused the reading on my phone's compass to change even from a distance of  something like four meters.

Answer (score -3):

I dont think the compass inside the phone is running with the help of magnet.
Instead they might have done the compass running with compass pointing towards the north,what ever might be the orientation of phones using some preinstruction or setting directions electrically.

Comment: Phones use a kind of solid state [magnetometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetometer) for their compasses. They should, I think, measure any magnetic field.

Comment: I dont think magnetometers and hall effect are distinct.They on a broad scale are one and the same.

Comment: @RonanCremin The magnetoresistive sensors cannot measure strong fields but they are better than Hall effect at low fields.

Comment: Re, "...using some preinstruction or setting directions electrically." Those words don't explain anything. In order for a compass to know which way to point, there must be some _physical phenomenon_ that the compass can _measure_. A magnetic compass senses the orientation of Earth's magnetic field lines. A GPS "compass" can't actually tell you which direction it points, but it can tell which direction it is moving based on very precise measurements of radio signals from satellites. etc.